# SQL concatenate query string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL script like below with some variables

```
declare @endDate datetime
declare @whereClause nvarchar(MAX)

set @whereClause = ' where endDate < ''' + @endDate + ''''
```

And here's the SQL select statement:

```
select * form TableName
```

What I want to do is the join the `@whereClause` and the select statement so the result should be

```
select * from TableNamewhere endDate < ''2013/11/2''
```

I've tried using the below statement to join the two string but I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

What's wrong with the below script? Or how can I join the two string?

```
select * from TableName + @whereClause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by using two varchar variables; one for the SELECT and one for the WHERE clause.

I.e.:

```
DECLARE @select AS nvarchar(max)
SET @select = 'SELECT * FROM TableName'

SET @select = @select + @whereClause
```

Comment: But how can I execute the @select nvarchar variable?

Comment: You could use sp_executesql for that:

    `EXEC sp_executesql @select`

Note that you'll have to supply a valid date for the statement to work, and that you will have to cast the date as a varchar value.